# Good references for dual-weighted residual (DWR) method for goal-oriented adaptive mesh refinement (AMR)

Tags: finite-element, reference-request, adaptive-mesh-refinement

Can anyone help me with good references (books or papers) where I can learn about dual-weighted residual (DWR) method for goal-oriented adaptive mesh refinement (AMR)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical "first" reference for the method is a paper by Becker and Rannacher that was ultimately published as an article in the ENUMATH 97 proceedings, but is often cited as the following preprint:

> R. Becker, R. Rannacher: "A feed-back approach to error control in finite element methods: basic analysis and examples". IWR preprint, University of Heidelberg, 1996.

Because of the difficulty of actually locating this preprint, Becker and Rannacher later wrote a longer article on the subject in Acta Numerica:

> R. Becker, R. Rannacher, "An optimal control approach to a posteriori error estimation in finite element methods," Acta Numerica, vol. 10, pp. 1–102, May 2001.

Then Rannacher thought "Why stop at 102 pages if I could write a whole book about the subject", and this led to the following book (disclaimer, if it's not obvious: I'm one of the co-authors):

> W. Bangerth, R. Rannacher: "Adaptive finite element methods for differential equations". Birkhäuser, 2003.

I believe that these are the three most frequently cited resources on the DWR method for error estimation and mesh adaptation.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look at the arXiv preprint of

- [B. Keith, A. V. Astaneh, and L. Demkowicz, "Goal-oriented adaptive mesh refinement for non-symmetric functional setting."](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.01996)

In this article, the authors motivate and present a new duality theory for FEM. Some overview of dual-weighted residual is also given (Section 5).

It also links to the very widely cited:

- [R. Becker, R. Rannacher, "An optimal control approach to *a posteriori* error estimation in finite element methods," *Acta Numerica*, vol. 10, pp. 1–102, May 2001.](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0962492901000010)

specifically for dual-weighted residual method.